# tableview instance method cellforrowatindexpath always returnd nil

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Table views instance method is always returns nil even if row are present in tableview for given indexpath

```
if let cell:AddExaminationNotesCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)) as? AddExaminationNotesCell{
    examinationNote = cell.examinationField.text
}
```

Comment: UITableViewCell are always reused. You cannot expect that the method cellForRowAtIndexPath: returns cell everytime. If the cell is not visible, it is nil.

Comment: What is implemented for cellForRowAtIndexPath? That should be a function you are providing as part of your delegate? Can you show the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath.